# Grab elements from array using indexes of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a Codewars problem and have been able to solve the majority of this problem except the final part. The challenge is **"rot13"**

**ROT13 is a simple letter substitution cipher that replaces a letter with the letter 13 letters after it in the alphabet. ROT13 is an example of the Caesar cipher. Create a function that takes a string and returns the string ciphered with Rot13.**

```
function rot13(message){
  message = message.split('');
  
  let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

  let indexes = message.map(char => alphabet.indexOf(char));

  let result = indexes.map(i => {
    let val = i + 13;
    let max = 26;
    if (val > max) {
      let temp = val - max;
      val = temp;
    }
    return val;
  });

  //result = [6, 17, 5, 6];
  //i want to use the elements in my result array, and
  //grab the letters from my alphabet array whose indexes associate with those elements from my result array

}
rot13('test') // 'grfg'
```

This is my current state in this problem. I have tried checking if any of the indexes of the elements in alphabet === the elements in my result array and if so, pushing those characters from the my alphabet array into an empty array but I am receiving **-1**

Any suggestions for approaching this problem/altering my thought process will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You need another map: `result.map(i => alphabet[i])`

Comment: Or, if you don't want a second `map`, do it in the one you already have: `return val;` -> `return alphabet[val];` You do need to `return result;` at the end of your function, though

Comment: Hi @Lain , when I return result I get the array [6, 17, 5, 6] however I want ['g','r','f','g'] so I can .join('') and get my final result which should be **'grfg'**

Comment: Be aware that this currently does not work with capital letters.

Comment: @blex thank you very much, that resolved my issue! I went with **return alphabet[val]** in my existing map and did a **return result.join('');**

Comment: @Lain thank you for pointing that out. I realize I need to consider capital letters and special characters. I should be able to resolve that. Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, you can just add:

`return results.map(i => alphabet[i]).join('')`

at the end of the function.

As a side note, instead of having an array of letters you can utilize the `String.fromCharCode` function. It translates a number into ASCII char equivalent (capital letters start at 65).

```js
function rot13(message){
  message = message.split('');
  
  let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

  let indexes = message.map(char => alphabet.indexOf(char));

  let result = indexes.map(i => {
    let val = i + 13;
    let max = 26;
    if (val > max) {
      let temp = val - max;
      val = temp;
    }
    return val;
  });
  
  return result.map(i => alphabet[i]).join('');
}
console.log(rot13('test')) // 'grfg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function rot13(message) {
  message = message.split('');

  let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

  return message.map(char => {
    let i = alphabet.indexOf(char);
    i = (i + 13) % alphabet.length;
    return alphabet[i];
  }).join("");
}

console.log(rot13('test')); // 'grfg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another `map()` to convert `result` back to characters by indexing `alphabet`. Then use `join('')` to make it a string. Then return it to the caller.

You can simplify the ROT13 calculation using modulus.

```js
function rot13(message) {
  message = message.split('');

  let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

  let indexes = message.map(char => alphabet.indexOf(char));

  let result = indexes.map(i => {
    let val = (i + 13) % 26;
    return val;
  });

  return result.map(i => alphabet[i]).join('');
}
console.log(rot13('test'));
```

Note that this will only work correctly if the string only contains lowercase letters. Anything else will return `-1` from `indexOf`, and you'll need to check for that.

Comment: Maybe simpler to remove the second `map` and just have one?

Comment: @blex I think it's easier to see all the steps by splitting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function rot13(message){
  message = message.split('');
  let finalResult = "";
  const alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

  message.forEach(item => {
    const index =  alphabet.indexOf(item);
    let cipherIndex = index + 13;
    if(cipherIndex > 25)
        cipherIndex = index - 13

    finalResult = finalResult + alphabet[cipherIndex]
  })
  return finalResult;
}
```